# How to achieve reuse of similar tkinter windows while also querying sqlite db

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I am making a pilot's logbook program, which will store my flights electronically, as a project to help me learn programming. It's basically a tkinter CRUD program which might eventually show some statistics on a welcome page dashboard.

I noticed that several of my tkinter windows are just rehashes of the same theme so i'd had the "DRY" idea that I could pass through a variable into the Toplevel window class to then tell - e.g. the function attached to a search button - where the request had come from. The function could then query a Sqlite database based on a dynamically generated query from a data structure like a dictionary, as in the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import sqlite3 as sqlite3

db_path = 'logbook_data.db'

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Logbook')
    root.geometry("600x300")
    
    app = Application(root)
    app.mainloop()
    
def lookup_window(source):
    lookup_window = tk.Toplevel()
    title_str = str("Select " + source + "...")
    lookup_window.title(title_str)
    lookup_frame = LookupWindow(lookup_window, source)
    lookup_frame.pack()

def search_selection(term, source):
    #Origin and Destination here are the same, but other
    # uses of the LookupWindow class will be different.
    source_dict = { "origin" : ('id,name', 'airports', 'name', term,),
                    "destination" : ('id, name', 'airports', 'name', term,)
                   }
    dbcon = sqlite3.connect(db_path)
    result = dbcon.execute('''SELECT ? FROM ? WHERE ? LIKE ?''',
                           source_dict[source])
    dbcon.close()
    return result


class Application(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master= None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master = master)
        self.pack()
        self.create_application()
        
    def create_application(self):
        self.origin_label = ttk.Label(self, text = "Origin Airport : ")
        self.origin_label.pack()
        self.origin_entry = ttk.Entry(self, state = "readonly")
        self.origin_entry.pack()
        self.origin_button = ttk.Button(self, text = "Lookup...",
                            command = lambda: lookup_window(source = "origin"))
        self.origin_button.pack()
        self.destination_label = ttk.Label(self,
                                           text = "Destination Airport : ")
        self.destination_label.pack()
        self.destination_entry = ttk.Entry(self, state = "readonly")
        self.destination_entry.pack()
        self.destination_button = ttk.Button(self, text = "Lookup...",
                       command = lambda: lookup_window(source = "destination"))
        self.destination_button.pack()


class LookupWindow(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master = None, source = None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master = master)
        self.source = source
        self.create_lookup_widgets()
    
    def create_lookup_widgets(self):
        self.select_entry = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.select_entry.pack(side = "left")
        self.select_button = ttk.Button(self, text = "Search", 
                    command = lambda: search_selection(self.select_entry.get(),
                                                       self.source))
        self.select_button.pack(side = "left")
        self.select_list = ttk.Scrollbar(self)
        self.select_list.pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I'd then populate the Scrollbar with the results so the user can click on one and return it to the previous window.

When I implemented this concept I received the 'sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error' and learnt that for sql injection security purposes you cannot parameterise sql objects. Fair enough.

How can I achieve reuse of the window class? Is there some posh, advanced implementation of decorators or something else I could use?

Or is this scenario an exception to the common practice of DRY?

Comment: I think placeholders cannot be used for column names. Use `f` instead or `format()` method

Comment: Give this a try: `dbcon.execute(f'''SELECT {source_dict[source][0]} FROM {source_dict[source][1]} WHERE {source_dict[source][2]} LIKE ?''',source_dict[source][3])`

Comment: @Cool Cloud - Thanks for replying. I'd interpreted the python sqlite3 docs to mean that substitution in this manner is insecure, hence why they suggest you use ? as a placeholder. [link] https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#module-sqlite3

Comment: If your concerned about safety, you should use SQLAlchemy as other than that I dont think any other method can be used.

Comment: @CoolCloud Thanks, I've managed to get the original implementation to work by placing the whole query into the dictionary rather than building it dynamically. When I've got the time I'll come back and post my resolution. I'll look in to sqlalchemy too.